# Como usar âncora no AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, front-end

Estou começando a trabalhar com AngularJS e tenho a seguinte situação
Tenho um href que redireciona para uma div dentro da própria página pelo id da div:

```
<a href="#teste"></a>
<div id="teste"></div>
```

porém o AngularJS tenta ler esse teste chamado pelo href como se fosse uma view, alguém sabe como contornar isso? Talvez algo que faça o href identificar que é âncora e não uma view, ou então outra forma que vocês saibam é também bem vinda.

Comment: Não tá faltando o `#` antes? Tipo: **`href="#teste"`**

Comment: Você pode utilizar um componente `router` para gerenciar as rotas da sua aplicação. [Essa documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router) pode te ajudar com a implementação inicial

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente isso não tem nada a ver com o Angular, só está faltando o **`#`** no `href`.

Veja funcionando:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

div {
  width: 90%;
  height: 120vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<a href="#teste">Ir para DIV</a>
<div></div>
<div id="teste" class="blue">
</div>
```

Comment: Então, esse é meu problema. Quando eu coloco o #teste no href. o meu projeto tenta ler uma 'view', e tenta redirecionar para uma página cujo endereço é meu endereço local /teste

Comment: Consegui resolver, criei um isLogin no $scope do meu login controller e ao invés de usar o href, eu apenas chamo o método do controller e atualizado esse isLogin para true ou false, e consigo habilitar pelo *ngIf a aba de logar ou a aba de cadastrar.

Answer (score 0):

vocẽ pode usar um target="_self" no seu href isso vai impedir a ação por parte do angularjs

```
<a href="#teste" target="_self"></a>
<div id="teste"></div>
```